# Creating Virtual layer in QGIS that shows only features in extent

Tags: qgis, sql, features, virtual-layer, qgsmapcanvas

I am trying to make a Virtual layer that is based on a map layer that only returns the features in the current map canvas extent. The purpose is to setup a Data Graph that shows statistical data of only the features in the current map extent.

I cannot find any examples of this being done in QGIS or using SQL. Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick is to create a function that access QGIS graphical interface, and that is piped to the query of the virtual layer.

1. Open a function editor (from anywhere, including from field calculator) and create a new function that reads the canvas extent and returns it as a geometry.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def currentExtent(feature, parent):
    return QgsGeometry.fromRect(iface.mapCanvas().extent())
```

2. Create a new virtual layer and use the new function, selecting features that intersects the displayed area. To get features entirely within the displayed area, use [`ST_Within()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html) instead.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM mylayer
WHERE st_intersects(mylayer.geometry, currentExtent());
```

Note that if you have the attribute table open, you would need to click the refresh icon after panning the map.

Comment: How will this handle features that are partially outside the map canvas?

Comment: @csk Since it uses `st_intersects`, features that are partially displayed will be returned. One can change the query and use `ST_Within` instead (or any other spatial predicate)

Comment: @csk and since it return `*`, the original (complete) geometry will be returned

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That's what I suspected, but wanted to be sure. A large feature that only slightly extends into the map canvas could have an unexpected impact on the graph.

Comment: I didn't know **custom expressions** could be used in virtual layers ... that's cool ... i suppose they can have a big impact on queries execution times ... ?

Comment: @snaileater I guess it depends on what the function does. I made this `currentExtent` function + virtual layer in an attempt to improve display performance of a big layer... and it had 0 effect

Comment: It says my layer has no field geometry

Comment: @TylerVeinot it is the default name. If you have another name (common if the data comes from Postgis), replace `geometry` by the real field name

Comment: Ha! Sorry, I had the geometry section set to defined It worked when I turned it too autondetect. This is very similar to my first attempt my function returned the min max xy's and in the SQL I had it making a polygon out of those values to intersect with. It was only giving me the extent that the map was at the time I made the query; Your approach not only is much cleaner but also auto updates to the new extent, can you tell me what part of the code is doing this for future reference?

Comment: @TylerVeinot when panning, the virtual layer query is (re)executed, so it calls the `currentExtent` function (each time) and filters the data accordingly. The same occurs when opening/refreshing the attribute table.

Comment: Makes sense, I didn't get a chance to use mine in the virtual layer I only ran it in the expression builder.

Comment: Is it possible to add a new function using python? I would like to add the function when    a plugin is started. Thanks.

Comment: @doktoreas Please create a new question with all the important information (add a new function to what? based on what? from your own plugin or a 3rd party one? etc). You can link to this question if needed

Comment: This can probably be made faster by using `_search_frame_` in the query: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#use-of-indexes