# Disjoint is very slow in Virtual Layer but fast on symbology

Tags: qgis, performance, intersect, virtual-layer

In QGIS, take a polygon grid (named `'grid'`) and a multipolygon layer (named `'surfaces'`).

For each feature in surfaces, I want to union all features of the grid that are disjoint (not intersected) with. I need to do this with a virtual layer (datasets regularly updated and exported with an atlas).

I have tried this two solutions, they work but are extremely slow (4-5 minutes):

```
select s.id, st_union(g.geometry)
from grid g, surfaces s
where not(st_intersects(g.geometry,s.geometry)) -- st_dissolve also works but is slower...
group by s.id
```

---

```
select s.id, st_union(g.geometry)
from grid g
join surfaces s on not(st_intersects(g.geometry,a.geometry))  -- st_dissolve also works but is slower...
group by s.id
```

The problem seems to be the `intersects`. The time is about the same with or without `st_union`.

For testing, I tried to add a rule-based symbology to my grid, with this rule:

```
not(intersects($geometry, @atlas_geometry ))
```

And I get the result instantly. Why intersects is slow on the Virtual Layer and fast in symbology? And how can I get a fast result in the Virtual layer?

---

EDIT

What I want to achieve (without union to see the grid):
[image: result with grid visible]

And with union, to calculate the area of each part of the grid:
[image]

Comment: How many features do you have in `'grid'` and `'surfaces'` layers? What are the technical characteristics of your system?

Comment: I guess you created a spatial index on both of your layers? Could you try using virtual fields with field-calculator and QGIS expressions? They will also update automatically.

Comment: In the virtual layer, you are computing the intersection/union for every shape between the two layers (that's a LOT of computation!), while in the ruled based symbology you are computing the intersection between 1) the visible geometries and 2) a single atlas geometry, which is likely involving just a few shapes. How are you using/timing the virtual layer?

Comment: @Babel Yes I have indexed my two layers. And I can't use virtual fields because output of my virtual layer because they can't create new features.

Comment: @JGH The goal is to make an atlas for every feature in `'surfaces'` and show the empty spaces symbolized by the grid - and calculate area for each.

Comment: @Taras In `'grid'` there are a lot of features (dependig of my QGIS projects, 2000 to 10000). In `'surfaces'` are only max 10 features. And my computer is "standard" Win10x64 i7 8Go ram.

Comment: you can try to [limit the features to the visible ones](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320991/how-to-create-a-virtual-layer-in-qgis-that-shows-only-the-features-in-the-extent/320994#320994) before doing the group-by

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#use-of-indexes

Answer (score 10):

The issue is the cross join on non-intersection. Your query reads:

- *for **every row in `g`**, return **every row in `s`** that does not intersect with the current `g`*

which seems in fact what you want, but about the *worst performing operation* on unfiltered and non-indexed relations in SQL.

Example: for 100 rows in `g` and 100 rows in `s`, and with *no intersection between any of them*, you would get **10.000 rows in return** that will then get grouped in a (costly) geometric union.

---

QGIS likely utilizes a low-level, in-memory index structure on loaded layers, and the expression is executed on features inside the view-port only - both of these facts do not apply to *SQLite*-interpreted *Virtual Layers*.

Comment: That last sentence is great.  Helps me understand why they are so slow sometimes

Comment: It may be that it's not even related to an index in the stricter sense, but that expressions on symbology is a graphic culling mechanic, in which case it's GPU powered. In any way, to achieve better performance on the base data, that data should live in a data format that allows for indexing, and a better performing query (e.g. using `NOT EXISTS (<sub-query>)`, or `NOT IN (<sub-query)` ).