# Selecting features visible in map extent using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, select-by-expression

In QGIS, I'm trying to select all the features that are visible in my map extent but I can't find a solution with "select by expression" or something else.

I will use your tips inside modeler to make a buffer of 5 meters around my polygons, but only on those which are visible in my map extent.

Comment: I tried `within ($geometry, @map_extent)`, but unfortunately, it does not work. But the answer by @JGH should solve your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick is to create a function that access QGIS graphical interface, and that is piped to the query of the `select by expression`.

1. Open a function editor (from anywhere, including from field calculator) and create a new function that reads the canvas extent and returns it as a geometry.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def currentExtent(feature, parent):
    return QgsGeometry.fromRect(iface.mapCanvas().extent())
```

2. Open the `select by expression` and use `intersects($geometry,currentExtent())` (or `within(..)` for entirely contained polygons)

The same function can be used in a virtual layer as shown [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/320994/84870), that you could eventually modify to compute the buffer.