# Graphical modeler: extract by expression on multiple sources

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to make a model in QGIS, which do the following steps:

1. Use the input `multiple input`, so I can select different vector layers (sometimes one, sometimes much more).
2. Use the algorithm `extract by expression`, using the following expression [QGIS: Select features visible in map extent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411311/qgis-select-features-visible-in-map-extent)
3. Use the algorithm `package layer`to save the result into a geopackage.

My problem is that I can't link the `extract by expression` with the input `multiple input`.
[image]