# Redraw a Point in the lower left corner (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, point, expression, extents, mapcanvas

I want to draw a point in the lower left corner of the QGIS map window (canvas). I tried the geometry genarator in the layer attributes:

```
point_n(@map_extent, 1)
```

This works, but I want the point really to be in the corner and not just the symbol. I need this, because I want to be able to klick on the point to select it.

I tried to write the map extend coordinates in an virtual attribut field (x and y) to catch them with a Virtual Layer and this query:

```
Select id, make_point(x, y, 31256) as geometry FROM Koordinaten
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Has anyone an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a point geometry at the bottom left of the current map canvas that dynamically changes by first creating a virtual field with the coordinates of this point in any of your vector layers. Then you can access these coordinates a virtual layer query to create the point.

1. Inside field calculator (to create coordinates), the variable `@map_extent` from QGIS expressions is not available. So you have to create a custom function for the task to create the map canvas extent, see here how: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411313/88814 (thanks @katagena [for the hint in the comment to this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/439295/88814)).

   Then create two fields `canvx` for the x-coordinate with `x_min(currentExtent())` and do the same for `canvy` with `y_min(currentExtent())`.
2. New create a virtual layer with this query and replace `my_layer` with the name of the layer that contains the attributes `canvx` and `canvy`:

   ```
    SELECT MakePoint (p.x , p.y) FROM color as p where p.id=1;
   ```

   The `where p.id=1` part is optional, but is to avoid creating one and the same point at the bottom left separately for each feature in your layer. Change the `id=1` part so that it fits your data.

Comment: I need the point to be changed dynamically when the map extend changes.

Comment: Thank you Babel!

Comment: You can skip extracting the coordinates, and directly create a virtual layer with the expression `SELECT MakePoint (xmin(currentExtent()) , ymin(currentExtent()))`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had in mind that QGIS expressions can be use in Virtual Layer queries, but was not sure if all or just some expressions.