# Get extent of the current map canvas in a virtual layer query in QGIS

Tags: qgis, extents, spatialite, virtual-layer, mapcanvas

Is it possible to get the extent of the current map canvas in a virtual layer query? Something similar to the [variable `@map_extent`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables) in QGIS expressions that can be used to create a polygon covering the current map canvas extent with Geometry generator.

In [SpatialLite's SQL functions reference list](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html), I don't see any function to get the map canvas extent. There is the function `Extent`, but it requires an existing geometry as input.

See [here for background](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439278/88814) about what this is used for.

Comment: Does it help?https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411311/selecting-features-visible-in-map-extent-using-qgis

Comment: Indeed it does, thanks, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439278/88814

Comment: This question looks like it can be closed because it's the above comments

Comment: Would leave it open - maybe ther are other people with different solutions. The linked answer is a workaround. Would still be great to get a direct solution in SpatialLite, thus what I originally asked for - or a confirmed answer that this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spatialite can't know what extent is being displayed, as this falls under the GUI "responsibility".

Therefore, the only way to know the displayed extent is via a function on the GUI side (either a custom function like in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320991/creating-virtual-layer-in-qgis-that-shows-only-features-in-extent/320994#320994), or a QGIS embedded function, or a function associated to a keyword... it's all the same under the hood)