# Filter Value Relation dropdown list based on canvas visibility/zoom level in QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis, forms, valuerelation

I have a point feature (Pontos_de_monitoramento) and another non-spatial table (ficha_campo).
I am adding new features to the non-spatial table (ficha_campo) and one of the fields to be filled in is the `NAME_POINT` field from the feature in Pontos_de_monitoramento, figure below.

[image: Example of QGIS project]

I prepared a form as shown in the figure below, using the Value Relation widget relating the `NAME_POINT` field from the ficha_campo table with the `NAME_POINT` field from the Pontos_de_monitoramento table, so that all the values from features in the Pontos_de_monitoramento table are listed for me to choose from, but the list is very large.

I would like to know if the list can be reduced, showing only the points that are visible on the screen when filling out the table.

[image: Forms AT QGIS]

[image: list of names to be chosen]

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there isn't an in-built function to get the canvas extent just yet, but you could create a custom function to do so.

1. Follow the instructions in step 1 of JGH's answer to [Selecting features visible in canvas extent](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411313/98784) to create a custom function to get the canvas extent.
2. Then under the Filter section of your Value Relation widget, use the expression `intersects($geometry,currentExtent())`

### [image]

Please note though performance can be slow on large datasets. You may need to create a custom Python function that can perform the intersection more efficiently.

Example below is with a point dataset of 45000 features.

[image]

Comment: Will this created function "currentExtent" work on any machine where I open the QGZ project, or only on the machine where I created it?
How can I get it incorporated into QGZ so it can work anywhere?

Comment: I think it's possible to save the custom function into the project instead of user profile by moving the script into the startup macros section per https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39330 - although this is from a few years ago. Each device would also need to enable macros in qgis settings I think. To use the function script in macros it might need slight tweaking, I haven't tried it myself

Comment: I tried but I couldn't Associate custom Python functions with a project instead of a user profile. Is there any other way to do what was suggested in the channel https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39330    so that it works in any QGIS project?
​