# Counting points from layer at map extent with QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, count, qgis-expression, aggregate, extents

I want to create an expression in the QGIS 3.28 dashboard layer that counts points on a specific point_layer and with a specific value that is displayed in the current map_extent view

```
aggregate(
   layer:='point_layer', 
   aggregate:='count', 
   expression:="field1", 
   filter:="field1"='3' AND within(.. ???.. )
   )
```

Comment: you can use the function from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320991/creating-virtual-layer-in-qgis-that-shows-only-features-in-extent/320994#320994) to get the current extent as a geometry

Comment: i dont want to create virtual layer

Comment: you cans till create and use the function :)

Comment: could you explain in more detail how to invoke this function inside expression ... i am not familiar with using functions

Comment: Please be aware you have a spelling mistake in your expression. `whithin` should be `within`.

Comment: See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#function-editor) for how to define and use a custom function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`@map_extent`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables) variable returns the current extent:

```
aggregate(
   layer:='point_layer', 
   aggregate:='count', 
   expression:="field1", 
   filter:="field1"='3' AND within(@geometry, @map_extent)
   )
```

Comment: thank you webrian & Taras ... it is working well