# Orientating Contour Labels Uphill in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, contour

I'm quite new to QGIS and I'm trying to style topographic contours. I have managed to style the lines the way I'd like but I'm having trouble with the line labels - I can't style them so the labels are orientated uphill.

This question is similar to [How to place elevation numbers on contours with uphill orientation and position?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26702) except I want to be able to export the style as an SLD as well. I hope the image below explains what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: What I have vs What I want]